Message flow limiting rule design
I am currently encountering a problem at work. Please allow me to describe it. The problem is like this. I have a system connected to a kafka data source. The message format is:
{"channel":"app","title":"hello","destIds":"111,222,333,444,555,666,777,888,999"}

destIds can be transmitted up to 10,000 at a time, and the total amount of data is more than 10 million.
Now there is a requirement that I need to limit the number of messages based on the set destId and channel through configuration options. For example, the number 111 can receive up to 10 messages in a day. I thought of using redis as a strategy, but string, These types of hash are not suitable. How should I design it without affecting the performance of my existing system? There are currently 5 spring boot service nodes consuming kafka data. I need help and suggestions.
I tried to use the set type of redis, but each message takes several seconds to process, which greatly slows down the consumption power of my system. I currently have no other good solution.
